# What is Guerilla testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application, gui, windows

What exactly does Guerilla Testing cover?

What can be done in Guerilla Testing?

> Why is Guerilla Testing used?

Is Guerilla Testing especially for **UX Design**?

Comment: [This question was mentioned on Meta](http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/q/397/18919)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer 1 ##

When talking about user testing in the UX circles, there’s formal user testing, and then there’s guerilla testing. Formal user testing is the subject of many research papers and studies, but there is relatively little guideline on how guerilla testing should be conducted. Although many UX purists frown on the practice, guerilla testing has become a useful tool for the everyday UX practitioner. Whether they be struggling with tight UX budgets or looming project deadlines, guerilla testing can help fast track the research and testing phases of their UX design cycle. In fact some UX practitioners might even refer to the practice as the art of guerilla testing.

In essence, guerilla testing is user research done using a lean and agile approach. While this means making the user testing simple, short and relatively flexible, it doesn’t mean going about this in a totally unstructured, undocumented and unplanned fashion. What formal testing tries to avoid by not conducting research and testing in a haphazard manner is the risk of introducing potentially costly design changes that may not lead to any benefits to the end user.

Yet, the danger of guerilla testing comes from poorly planned and executed tests that are not reliable, consistent or meaningful. In this post, we’ll explore some pitfalls of guerilla testing “in the wild,” a few tactics to avoid or minimize the methodology’s weaknesses and tips to improve planning for all research and testing.
[Describes What is Guerrilla Testing](http://www.loop11.com/the-importance-of-planning-in-guerilla-testing/)
  ## Answer 2 ##

A fast and vicious attack on the program. A form of exploratory testing that is usually time-boxed and done by an experienced exploratory tester. For example, a senior tester might spend a day testing an area that will otherwise be ignored. She tries out her most powerful attacks. If she finds significant problems, the area will be re budgeted, and the overall test plan might be affected. If she finds no significant problems, the area will hereinafter be ignored or only lightly tested

Hints for Guerilla Testing https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/10-hints-for-carrying-out-better-guerrilla-usability-testing

Guerilla Usability Testing http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-art-of-guerrilla-usability-testing/

Comment: Perhaps you could combine your two answers into one answer.

Comment: i cannot able to edit dude.... when i delete an answer it was remains same and displays option to undelete so only i have posted next good answer again.

Comment: You could delete both your answers and create a new one that merges your two answers.  It is normal for your answer to remain visible to you after you delete it.

Comment: yea i have done it.... but still the deleted answer displaying...

Comment: @Paarthiban NK, If you are Asking a question, answering your own asked question and accepted your own answer even they don't have single positive votes. 
Then why are you asked this type of questions? If you are doing only for time pass, this is the worst case. Think about it.

Answer (score 8):

As of my reading-

> **Guerrilla Testing** means going into a coffee shop or another public place to ask people there about your product or prototype. It can be conducted anywhere ex- cafe, library, train station etc, essentially anywhere where there is significant footfall.

Guerrilla testing works well to quickly validate how effective a design is on its intended audience, whether certain functionality works in the way it is supposed to, or even establishing whether a brand or proposition is clear.

This approach is quick and relatively easy to set up. Participants are not recruited but are ‘approached’ by those persons conducting the sessions. The sessions themselves are short, typically between 15-30 minutes and are loosely structured around specific key research objectives. The output is typically ‘qualitative’ so insight is often rich and detailed.
Anyone on the service team can conduct ‘guerrilla testing’ on their site or service.

> Guerrilla testing can be used throughout the service life cycle.

Comment: of course.. you are correct.. Guerrilla Testing is for all domains. Even testing is for **All Domains**. we have to just use the concept to our domain.

Comment: what were you reading?  could you add some quotation and references/citation for us please, maybe a link?

Answer (score 4):

## What is Guerrilla Testing:

It is a way to get some quick user feedback on your product or prototype. I can say its usability testing.

## Guerrilla Testing Covers:

It covers an activity by which you need to conduct it where your audience are novice users and observe these -

- *Can they find the content?*
- *Is the language relevant to them?*
- *Have they understood what they’ve read?*

## What can be done in Guerrilla Testing?:

### Venue

- Where will you find your audience?
- Can they stop for 10 minutes?
- Will you have internet access?

### Devices

- Which devices does your audience use?
- Can you record from that device?

### Practiced introduction

- Who are you?
- Why are you there?
- What do you want from them?

### Scenarios

- Which user need are you testing?
- What might create that need?
- When has a user fulfilled that need?

### In conclusion

- Pick a location where your audience is
- Focus your session on scenario based tasks
- Let participants decide success
- Understand what they’d do next

## Why Guerrilla Testing is Used:

It is cheap simple and effective.

## Is Guerrilla Testing Especially for UX Design?:

It is for UX and UI.

Comment: Do you have any references to where you found this information, or is it general knowledge?

Answer (score 3):

Gorilla Testing is a testing technique in which testers or developers also join to  testers to test a particular module thoroughly in all aspects.

Gorilla Testing is a  technique in which repetitive Manual Testing process, which a tester would have done several times before, is done again to test the robustness of the system.

Here, one module of the program is tested over and over again to ensure that it is working properly and  that there are no bugs in module. The module can be tested over a hundred times, and with the same process. Hence, the testing process includes the tester running the same code over and over again.

Comment: Actually, Gorilla testing and Guerilla testing aren't quite the same thing. Guerilla testing is grabbing random potential users and asking them to try your application to see how it works for them. Gorilla testing is a form of stress/reliability testing as you've described.

Comment: I think you are confusing a Guerilla fighter with a Gorilla: https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/gorilla-guerrilla/

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does Guerrilla Testing cover?

Many people equate Guerrilla usability testing with QA Services. You don’t actually need much equipment or software testing company to run a usability test. Just a computer to run the test, somebody to moderate and somebody to take notes. Instead of a note taker, I prefer to set up a video recorder pointed at the screen. This captures the mouse movements as well as the audio, so you don’t need to take notes.

Alternatively you could have two videos, one recording the screen and one recording the person. Or a video and some screen capture software. However you then need to composite both feeds and this can get complicated.

Guerrilla testing tends to be carried out anywhere possible, from an empty meeting room to a local cafe. It’s usually (although not necessarily) carried out on a one-to-one basis by a member of the design team. Guerrilla testing is a way to get some quick user feedback on your product or prototype and it leads to more add-ons in the quality improvements for your product.

Instead of focusing on quantitative data, these tests usually focus on qualitative data for design insight rather than statistical validity.

What can be done in Guerrilla Testing?

In Guerrilla testing, software testing company is going to target the audience who can provide a genuine feedback for the product and hence , a  product with quality, robustness as well as meeting the main consumers requirements can be implemented.

Following are the steps which are performed for such kind of testing:

a)A session for the product is provided to the targeted audience.
b)Devices,environments  and other hardware requirements are facilitated to the audience or the such kind of audience is targeted which leads to low cost for such setups..
c)Feedback is received from the targeted audience .
d)Feedback can be converted into improvements  and may be treated as consumer requirements .Hence a new cycle of development and QA testing is conducted for this new feedback and product can be prototyped as per the new requirements.

Why is Guerrilla Testing used?

Guerrilla research are faster, lower-cost methods that provide sufficient enough insights to make informed strategic decisions. In fact, using Guerrilla testing method is a great way to introduces software companies to the value that research can bring to projects.

ADVANTAGES OF GUERRILLA TESTING-

```
 Uses minimum resources-people, cost.
 No specialist or technology is required.
 It can be performed in various locations like cafes, library.
 It works well with Agile Methodology Approach.
 It helps uncover unexpected issues or highlights unnecessary features.
 It is great for testing the system at the early stages of it's development.
```

Is Guerrilla Testing especially for UX Design?

Yes ,Guerrilla testing is for UX Design as UX(User Experience) Design is the process of enhancing user satisfaction by improving the usability, accessibility, and pleasure provided in the interaction between the user and the product